# losing cookie and timeout

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
    <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms path="/" defaultUrl="Default.aspx" loginUrl="Login.aspx" name=".ASPXAUTH" slidingExpiration="true" timeout="3000" cookieless="UseDeviceProfile"/>
    </authentication>

    private void SetAuthticationCookie(string username)
    {
        FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(username, true, 3000);
        string encTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
        HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encTicket);
        Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
    }
```

it works fine in the local computer but when I have sent web application to host server it lost cookie very soon so how I can increase time for two days ?

**Added note :** I test with "fire cookie plugin" but there is no cookie set on my web site it is so cool ! I don't know why ? In fact there is cookie because I close Firefox and then run it again my site load data from cookie but the problem is expiration time.

**Added log-trace :**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 20 Mar 2011 06:19:13 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-Powered-By: PleskWin
Set-Cookie: .ASPXANONYMOUS=6ASaj1gdzAEkAAAAOGU0YTk2NmItNjhiMy00MGIzLTgyYzAtNTc1YThiNmRhNThl0; expires=Sat, 28-May-2011 16:59:09 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=at5qoanwkc31y0xuguomabgw; path=/; HttpOnly
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 148363
```

Comment: yes it is not dedicated it is share

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your forms "name" attribute to something else...are you able to use something like FireBug (or FireCookie) to check what cookies are loaded (and there expiration dates?)

**Edit**
**Remove** the **path** attribute completely from your declaration...see if that helps...

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms defaultUrl="Default.aspx" loginUrl="Login.aspx" name=".ASPXAUTH" slidingExpiration="true" timeout="3000" cookieless="UseDeviceProfile"/>
</authentication>
```

Comment: FireCookie plugin doesn't show anything and that is so cool there is no cookie but in fact there is cookie because I close the firefox and then run it again it's fine but the expiration is problem